# OnDraw function drawing ontimer

Tags: timer, gdi, ondraw

I want to draw something after every 1 second. It means i have to put code for drawing in onTimer function. How can i do that? I can't call OnDraw or any other function that has CDC* pDC as an argument. Is there any way to draw something in ontimer function?

Comment: You missed some tags like MFC...

Answer (score 0):

There is no Need to do that. You have several choices:

1. In your OnTimer handler just call InvalidateRect/Invalidate, let the message pump o the update.
2. Call InvalidateRect/Invalidate and than UpdateWindow. This will update the window immediately.
3. Just call RedrawWindow with the required parameter... (same as effect 2.)